# Removing YOURLS branding from stat page

Tags: javascript, php, statistics, customization, yourls

First off, here is my url: http://tini.link

So, basically, everything is going well. I have a completely custom homepage, with anti-spam and all that. Then a results page, with all sorts of special stuff. But, I want to customise the stats page.

I have worked out how to customise the admin pages. It's in `includes/function-html.php`. But if you customise the menus in there, they do not carry over to stats page.

Any ideas on where I can customise the stats page?

Comment: What does `YOURLS` mean? URLs ? Also, provide code. It's impossible to understand the context here.

Comment: YOURLS is your own url shortner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from the question is, you need this - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Create the menu in a separate PHP file and include that wherever you need the menu. Assuming your menu is in `menu.php`

In both `includes/function-html.php` and `stats.php` (assumption), wherever you need the menu, do something as follows.

```
<?php
...

//include menu here
include 'path/to/your/menu.php';
...
```

By doing this, you can customize `menu.php` and it will reflect everywhere you have included it.

**NOTE -** Let me know in comments if that's not what you are looking for.